# Java Generics wildcard extends problem

Tags: java, generics

Could you please help me? Following code sample:

```
public abstract class AbstractWorker {  

    public abstract void execute();  

}  

public class Config {  

    public final String name;  

    public Config(final String name) {  
        this.name = name;  
    }  

}  

public abstract class AbstractWorkerFactory<C extends Config> {  

    public abstract AbstractWorker createWorker(final C configuration);  

}  

public class Service {  

    public AbstractWorker caramba(final AbstractWorkerFactory<? extends Config> factory, final Config configuration) {
        // it is not compile :(
        return factory.createWorker(configuration);
    }

}
```

Following code works

```
public <C extends Config> AbstractWorker caramba(final AbstractWorkerFactory<C> factory, final C configuration) {
    return factory.createWorker(configuration);
}
```

But code which uses Service couldn't specify generic type. Is it possible other solution. 
**UPDATE** (after answer by meriton): 
1. Concentrate Factory and Configuration instance create in different places (classes). 
2.

```
public static class MegoConfig extends Config {

public static class WorkerFactory extends AbstractWorkerFactory<Config> {

public static class MegoWorkerFactory extends AbstractWorkerFactory<MegoConfig> {
```

MegoWorkerFactory support MegoConfig and Config. 
New solution for my task.

```
public AbstractWorker caramba(final AbstractWorkerFactory<? super MegoConfig> factory, MegoConfig configuration) {
        return factory.createWorker(configuration);
}

new Service().caramba(new WorkerFactory(), new MegoConfig(""));
new Service().caramba(new MegoWorkerFactory(), new MegoConfig(""));
```

Many thanks to all for your answer!

Comment: Why couldn't the code which uses Service specify the generic type? Did it have an AbstractWorkerFactory<?>, or was it Java 1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration

```
public AbstractWorker caramba(final AbstractWorkerFactory<? extends Config> factory, final Config configuration) {
```

is too broad; it accepts any WorkerFactory with any configuration, not expressing that each workerfactory expects a specific configuration. That is, it would be entirely legal to write

```
caramba(new AbstractWorkerFactory<FooConfiguration>() { ... }, new BarConfig());
```

even though that WorkerFactory can not work with that configuration.

On the other hand, the declaration

```
public <C extends Config> AbstractWorker caramba(final AbstractWorkerFactory<C> factory, final C configuration)
```

correctly expresses that the supplied WorkerFactory must be compatiable with the supplied configuration, by means of the same type variable appearing in both parameter declarations.

> But code which uses Service couldn't specify generic type. Is it possible other solution?

I don't understand; why can't it? Why do you need another solution?

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your answer. I've updated post to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are these all in the same file? You can't have multiple public classes in a single source file. That wouldn't account for the generics error, though.

I threw these in a source file with your `Service` class, and got compilation just fine:

```
class Config {}
class AbstractWorker {}
abstract class AbstractWorkerFactory<C extends Config> {
    public abstract AbstractWorker createWorker(final C configuration);
}
```

What's the code that uses `Service`?

Answer (score 0):

No, the solution you provide is probably the best :

```
public <C extends Config> AbstractWorker caramba(final AbstractWorkerFactory<C> factory, final C configuration) {
    return factory.createWorker(configuration); 
}
```

Alternatively you could use the raw signature in the caramba method, without the wildcards, but that would bring other problems, such as compiler warnings.